# Open a report in ms access from python

Tags: python, ms-access

I am trying to open an MS Access report with `win32com` library, which work fine if one has the full application of ms access installed. It fails when the user has only the runtime installed.

```py
import win32com.client
a = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
```

is causing problems understandably.

Is there a other way of opening a report in MS Access without having a full installation of MS Access?

Comment: Review https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/613d5b25-213e-45d9-bb9b-4ff8d68bf41e/open-a-report-from-msaccess-2010-runtime-version-in-vbnet-windows-application and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you face two issues both of which requires the full MSAccess.exe installed.

- **COM Connection**: Any [Command Object Model (COM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model) connection be it with VBA, Python, or another language to an Office software requires installation of that software. Therefore, `Access.Application` will not be available if MSAccess.exe is not installed.
- **Report Component**: An MS Access report is an integral GUI object of MSAccess.exe (the Office software). Without full installation of the office software you cannot use its application components. The runtime simply allows execution of a previously built MS Access application but not developer access to actual objects. Arguably, the runtime uses a *compiled* version of Access app.

  With that said, MS Access is not just a software but also a database engine (i.e., [the multifaceted thing that is Access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33216)). Specifically, users do not need the full MSAccess.exe to connect or query from `.mdb` or `.accdb` files. Therefore, its tables and queries, underlying data components, are available to any Windows user, sufficing that the user uses a compliant ODBC/OLEDB library like Python's `pyodbc` or `adodbapi` that can connect to the database.

To answer final question, there may be not be another way to open an MS Access report without the Office software installed. But Python is a general-purpose language. So, avoid reliace on a software component. Instead, interact with the data itself and rebuild the report.  Since an MS Access report runs on table or query data, have Python connect to table or query data and rebuild the report with a variety of documentation or presentation types: `.html`, `.rst`, `.md`, etc.

Comment: thanks for you answer. i guess what you said is also valid for running a function (sub) stored in ms access. An idea was to have a function or macro in ms access that simply prints out a report. That could be triggered from python

Comment: Running VBA code inside an MS Access app still requires the `Access.Application` COM object.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime can only open Access applications. It can't open empty.

So you need to open Access with a 'database' before you can use it for any other purpose.

Once you have Access open with a 'database', either by running the executable or by opening with COM, then COM can attach to the existing process.